# Viewing Python 3.3 *.pyo file members

Tags: python-3.x, reflection

Some languages, like Java, C# and etc allows to view members (classes, methods, methods and attributes of classes) of the compiled file, without decompilation.

For example, NetBeans IDE could index compiled *.class and *.jar files and it will show you, what class is in the file, what members contains that class.

Is it possible to view, what *.pyo file contains? Does Python contains features, like reflection?

Thank you very much!

Comment: as in view it's original Python statements?

Comment: No, just what classes and what functions are in the file. For example - SomeClass.someFunction(arg1::Sim, arg2::Cloth)